# Any way to enable intellisense for coffeescript?

Tags: visual-studio-code, coffeescript

I got a trouble when i add tsd reference in *.cofff* file.

I try to add :`#<reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts"/>`

or `##<reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts"/>`

or `###<reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts"/>###`

but not thing happen. Any way to enable intellisense for Coffeescript?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode (0.3.0) currently has no context aware intellisense for Coffeescript. You can vote for that feature on [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code)